# Custom spinner loader for simple Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a [simple vue project on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/m5n730kw2j) with vue-router and custom spinner loading.

**Spinner.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div class="spinner" v-show="loading">
    <span class="sync" v-bind:style="[spinnerStyle, spinnerDelay1]"></span>
    <span class="sync" v-bind:style="[spinnerStyle, spinnerDelay2]"></span>
    <span class="sync" v-bind:style="[spinnerStyle, spinnerDelay3]"></span>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Spinner",
  props: {
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: "#5dc596"
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      default: "15px"
    },
    margin: {
      type: String,
      default: "2px"
    },
    radius: {
      type: String,
      default: "100%"
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      spinnerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: this.color,
        height: this.size,
            width: this.size,
        borderRadius: this.radius,
        margin: this.margin,
        display: 'inline-block',
        animationName: 'spinerAnimation',
        animationDuration: '1.25s',
        animationIterationCount: 'infinite',
        animationTimingFunction: 'ease-in-out',
        animationFillMode: 'both'
      },
      spinnerDelay1: {
        animationDelay: '0.07s'
      },
      spinnerDelay2: {
        animationDelay: '0.14s'
      },
      spinnerDelay3: {
        animationDelay: '0.21s'
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    start() {
      this.loading = true;
    },
    end() {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
};

</script>
```

Main page is **Home.vue** with links on other components:

```
 <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
 <router-link to="/helloworld">Hello World</router-link>
 <router-link to="/bigimg">Big Img</router-link>
```

And **main.js**:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";

import Spinner from "./components/Spinner";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  components: {
    App,
    Spinner
  },
  template: "<App/>"
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log("next page");
  //loading = true
  next();
});

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  //setTimeout(() => (loading = false), 1500);
});
```

Spinner Loader should be started when the main page (Home.vue) is loaded and when go to the subpage project (components).

**Question:** How can I launch the loader when I load the main page (Home) of the project and when I go to other pages of the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a state variable:

```
const state = {
    loading: false
};
```

Register it in your main.js file:

```
new Vue({
  ...
  data: {
    state
  },
});
```

Set a condition into your main template:

```
new Vue({
  ...
  template: '<App v-if="!state.loading" /><Spinner v-else/>'
});
```

And then set the state beforeEach route:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log("next page");
  state.loading = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    state.loading = false;
  }, 3000);
  next();
});
```